# how to convert an instance of an anonymous type to a NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, namevaluecollection

Suppose I have an anonymous class instance

```
var foo = new { A = 1, B = 2};
```

Is there a quick way to generate a NameValueCollection?  I would like to achieve the same result as the code below, without knowing the anonymous type's properties in advance.

```
NameValueCollection formFields = new NameValueCollection();
formFields["A"] = 1;
formFields["B"] = 2;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var foo = new { A = 1, B = 2 };

NameValueCollection formFields = new NameValueCollection();

foo.GetType().GetProperties()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(pi => formFields.Add(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(foo, null)?.ToString()));
```

Comment: how do you handle null value ?

Comment: @Kiddo with song in my heart and a high quality pair of adult diapers. Where do you have the null?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I get a null in some cases because you are calling `.ToString()` when in some cases `pi.GetValue` returns null. Changing it to  `pi.GetValue(vm, null)?.ToString()` has allowed me to overcome it.

Comment: I am getting an error null object reference. thanks –  solution of @sychich-rush works without error. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Another (minor) variation, using the static [`Array.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) method to loop through the properties...

```
var foo = new { A = 1, B = 2 };

var formFields = new NameValueCollection();
Array.ForEach(foo.GetType().GetProperties(),
    pi => formFields.Add(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(foo, null).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just about what you want:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = 
       foo.GetType()
          .GetProperties()
          .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => pi.GetValue(foo, null));

NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dict)
{
   nvc.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Using .ToList<T>.ForEach is faster than foreach

Comment: Good point. Forgot about that. But the real killer in my sln is the ToDictionary()

Comment: @Yuriy: If we're worrying about micro-optimisation then using `Array.ForEach` will be faster still, and doesn't require the intermediate `ToList` pass. (See my answer for an example.)

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer Yurity gave with one minor tweak to check for nulls.

```
var foo = new { A = 1, B = 2 };

NameValueCollection formFields = new NameValueCollection();

foo.GetType().GetProperties()
 .ToList()
 .ForEach(pi => formFields.Add(pi.Name, (pi.GetValue(foo, null) ?? "").ToString()));
```