# How can I get the values and count from a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to be able to get the values and count from any model I create.

For example let's say I have a model that looks like this.

```
public class test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to write code that will look at the model and then get ID, Name, Address and put them into an array. And I don't want the values. But the values from the model. Not the data. As well as getting the count of the values. 3.

Comment: "And I don't want the values. But the values from the model." Can you explain this more clearly?  I don't understand the difference between the two.

Comment: I want to get what makes up the model. Using the model above I would want to look inside and get the values are ID, Name and Address. Then put that into an list or array that I could then use elsewhere.

Comment: @Prescient I think I understand what you are looking for now. You can use reflection to extract the names into a list. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: If your requirement happens to be to create a `json` object, look at the class `JavascriptSerializer` within `System.Web.Script.Serialization` It will do the grunt work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: per your clarifications in the comments

You can use reflection to extract the property names into a list

```
var foo = new test();
IList<string> properties = foo.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

---

OLD ANSWER

Try converting your object to a NameValueCollection (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx). This collection offers a count, and allows you hash table access to the values. You can also retrieve an `IEnumerable` for the Values (or Keys) to suit your needs.

```
var foo = new test();

NameValueCollection formFields = new NameValueCollection();
foo.GetType().GetProperties()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(pi => formFields.Add(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(foo, null).ToString()));
```

NOTE: if `.ToString()` is too destructive, you can swap the `NameValueCollection` with the `IDictionary` implementation of your choice.

Code modified from this question: [how to convert an instance of an anonymous type to a NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838398/how-to-convert-an-instance-of-an-anonymous-type-to-a-namevaluecollection)

Comment: TY Kevin. You just saved my desk from destruction. lol

Answer (score 0):

In the other class simply call `test.ID = identification;`
`identification` being the variable that you would like ID to get the value from.
`test` being your class name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this (wrapped in example code).

```
class Program
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(Test).GetProperties();
        var propertyCount = propertyInfo.Count();

        Console.WriteLine($"Property count is {propertyCount}");
        foreach (var info in propertyInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Property Name: {info.Name}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Which would give you the output:

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gQUP.png)

This allows you to get the property count and property names of a class.